# Testing property set with a List in Rhino Mocks

Tags: list, mocking, properties, rhino

I feel like I have lost my mind because I am sure I have done this before. Hopefully one of you can point me in the right direction.

Essentially I have an view that I want to test that the presenter is correctly setting the property with a list of objects. Example:

```
public ComplexDto{
   public string name{get;set;}
   public string description{get;set;}
}

public interface ITestView{
 IList<ComplexDto> dto{get;set;}
}
```

Within the Presenter it sets a list like:

```
...
var dtos = new List<ComplexDto>();
dtos.add(new ComplexDto(){name="test name", description="this is some description"}
view.dto = dtos;
...
```

I need to test that that contents of the list of the dto work.

I have tried GetArgumentsForCallsMadeOn but I think this does not work with properties.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

This should do it:

```
var view = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ITestView>();
var dtos = new List<ComplexDto>();
dtos.Add(new ComplexDto() {name = "test name", description = "this is some description"});

List<ComplexDto> passedIn;
view.Expect(v => v.dto).SetPropertyWithArgument(dtos).WhenCalled(mi => passedIn = (List<ComplexDto>) mi.Arguments[0]);

view.dto = dtos;
view.VerifyAllExpectations();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't actually verify the contents of the List. It only verifies that the List is the same reference object. If you create two seperate list objects that containt the exact same ComplexDto values it fails. I need to compare the contents of the list to be sure the values are the same.

ComplexDto, btw, has hash and equality over rides to be sure it is comparing for equality correctly.

Comment: See my updated answer.  Use "WhenCalled" to grab the argument passed to the property setter.  Now you can do whatever verification you need on "passedIn".